# C++: static initialize an array member, member at a time

Tags: c++, arrays, static, initialization

I now I can do this in global scope and everything works fine:

```
const char* Foo::bars[3] = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

But I want to do this because this is much more clearer and self documenting (especially if you use Enums as the index):

```
const char* Foo::bars[3];
bars[0] = "a";
bars[1] = "b";
bars[2] = "c";
```

Is it anyway possible?

I know I can do this inside a function (for example, the class's constructor) but what if the constructor is not called in the start of the program and I want to use the static array? That leads to problems.

Comment: Why should the constructor not be called?

Comment: The OP wants Foo::bars to be a static member, and that its elements be initialized statically (before main is executed).

Comment: @Emile yes, and the OP's first line of code does exactly that, provided `bars` is declared static. Constructor will be invoked, so I miss the whole discussion's point.

Comment: @Simone, the OP is saying that, as a static initialization, the declaration alone that he is providing guarantees that it will be initialized.  If it is reliant on the ctor of another class, one must instantiate the class to guarantee the initialization of this list.  Obviously if *that* class is static also, then there is nothing to worry about, but it's worth mentioning as there's an extra link in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ there is no equivalent of the `static` Java block.

If you really want to initialize the array automatically, you can create a simple class to do the job:

```
// in .cpp
class FooInitializer {
public:
    FooInitializer() {
        Foo:bars[0] = "a";
        Foo:bars[1] = "b";
        Foo:bars[2] = "c";
    }
};

static FooInitializer fooInitializer;
```

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
const char* Foo::bars[3] = {
/* Index    Value */
/* 0 */     "a",
/* 1 */     "b",
/* 2 */     "c"
};
```

I often use this "technique" to make the initialization of arrays of structs look like a self-documenting spreadsheet.

Comment: If "the constructor is not called" it doesn't work, since it's the same code as the OP. Don't ask me why it shouldn't be called, anyway...

Comment: @Simone: The OP wants Foo::bars to be a static member, and wants them initialized before the program runs. But the OP doesn't like the initialization syntax. Yes, my the code is the same, but I added inline comments to make the array index visible for each array element. Crude, yes, but effective, IMHO.

Comment: This is even more useful when you have enum constants in there, but still requires re-organizing the array initialization if your enum changes order for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an accessor-function:

```
const char* GetArray()
{
    static char* result[3];
    static isInitialized = false;
    if (!isInitialized)
    {
        result[0] = "a";
        result[1] = "b";
        result[3] = "c";
        initialized=true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do the "a", "b", and "c" literals have local scope? I think this may result in dangling pointers.

Comment: I've done a little research... string literals indeed have global scope.

Comment: Please note that this solution is not thread-safe, because the function is not re-entrant.

Comment: This is also my favorite solution for declaring a `std::map` using literals, say if you wanted to create something like a translation table. These kinds of things have to happen at run-time. I think the OP is looking for something more cleanly like Python dictionary syntax, or something like that, but unfortunately with C++ implementation details get in the way. It is worth noting that C++0x will actually add syntax for initializing containers.

Comment: @Emile you can make it threadsafe using standard techniques like mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that uses the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern. Note that the array is initialized once in the singleton's constructor. Also note that this is not thread-safe. Also beware of the evilness of singletons (search this site for "singleton" to find some interesting debate on this matter).

```
#include <iostream>

class StringTable
{
public:
    enum StringId
    {
        hello,
        bye,
        goodDay,
        stringCount
    };

    static const char* lookup(StringId id) {return instance().table_[id];}

private:
    StringTable()
    {
        table_[hello] = "Hello World!\n";
        table_[bye] = "Goobye, cruel world!\n";
        table_[goodDay] = "I said good day!\n";
    }

    static StringTable& instance()
    {
        static StringTable theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }

    const char* table_[stringCount];
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << StringTable::lookup(StringTable::hello)
              << StringTable::lookup(StringTable::bye)
              << StringTable::lookup(StringTable::goodDay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an extra const in bars

```
const char* const Foo::bars[3] = 
{
   "a",
   "b",
   "c"
};
```

The way you declared it, you can actually do what you wanted in setting the members one at a time, although you'd use an "init" function to do it.

If you do want it const, which is probably preferable, it will subsequently become illegal to assign them a line at a time, even in some kind of "init" method and you should simply use a code layout to make it clearer what you are doing.